# what's the difference between GTK 3.14 and 3.18 on the css load

Tags: python, css, gtk

I finish a GTK interface with GTK3.18,and it works well,but when i change to GTK3.14 version,the interface turn out to be very bad,the size and the colore of the widgets is changed,and i find there is no enough information about the GTK3.14 version.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS 'api' was basically undocumented and unstable before 3.20 so there isn't really any reasonable way to support all versions before it unless you make a separate theme for each version.